# Visual Studio 2013 and data-member colourization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, customization

Has anyone found a way to change the colour that C++ data members are represented in the editor for VS2013?

It seems like you can change just about every other item's colour including general 'variables', 'local variables' and more obscure things like 'properties' and 'labels'.  Is it possible that data members are listed under some other description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you're after is named 'C++ Fields' under <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>Environment</kbd>-><kbd>Fonts and Colors</kbd>.